# Passport-JWT custom authorisation

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using Passport-jwt to authorize a user, however I am struggling to find a way of getting any kind of custom response in the case of a bad or missing token. in the case of a correct token, it all goes through and carries on the method. However in the case of a bad/missing token I always get a 401 response with no option to give back any custom message/information.

In the case of a real world example

What I want is some custom logic to say either

1) No you have not given a token at all

2) yes you gave a token but it was not decoded correctly so you made it up

My code

```html
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

var User = require('../app/models/user');
var config = require('./config');  

module.exports = function(passport) {
  var opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
  opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
  passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
    User.findOne({id: jwt_payload.id}, function(err, user) {
      console.log(jwt_payload);
          if (err) {
              console.log("err : " + err);
              return done(err, false);
          }
          if (user) {
              console.log("user : " + user);
              done(null, user);
          } else {
              console.log("No User");
              done(null, false);
          }
      });
  }));
};
```

I then use this for each request.

```html
apiRoutes.get('/test', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(err, user, info) {
  res.json({ message: 'All Good!' });
});
```

Comment: `console.log("No User"); done(null, false);` should have error object, `done(new Error('No User'), false);`

Comment: These console logs are not even hit, that is the point. In the case of not passing a token, nothing is hit in the entire code

Comment: Have you actually initialized passport?

Comment: Yes. Like I said, it works when I pass a valid token

Comment: It should be `User.findOne({_id: jwt_payload.id}, cb)`, note underscore